# Trouble setting up Path/to/rails for Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I'm following Ubuntu's guide to get Rails running on my newly installed Ubuntu (I'm very new to Linux in general).

I've installed Apache, MySQL and Ruby and Rails. I checked this by checking its versions and they work. Now the next step says I have to open my Apache conf and change some things to /path/to/rails/***.

But I have no clue whatsoever where my Rails is located. How can I figure this one out? Or what's the default given by Ubuntu?

I've tried searching my filesystem but that brings up so many results that it's not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it myself by removing everything and using another tutorial(Easy steps!)
http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/05/02/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've installed Rails via Gem, the easiest way to get its path would be to type `gem which rails` at the command line.

Note that Rails is actually made up of heaps of different gems though, like ActiveRecord, ActiveModel, ActionController, etc. If you want to find the folder that holds all of your gems (including all the different Rails gems), enter `rails env`, and go to the path labeled `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY`.

Comment: I didn't gem anything. I just installed apache, mysql and rails after as the tutorial suggested (sudo apt-get install rails). Perhaps this isn't the best/easiest way to install rails. In that case I'm open for suggestions! :-)

Comment: How about just trying `which rails`, then? Can you link me to the tutorial that you're using?

Comment: `which rails` didn't do anything. I used https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: I see what the issue is now! The tutorial wants you to enter the path to your Rails application, not Rails itself. I would follow this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html if I was you, and after you've made your first Rails app (with `rails new [app name]`), then you can enter its path into the Apache config.

Answer (score 0):

[The tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ruby-on-rails.html) says:

> The first thing to change is the DocumentRoot directive:
>
> > DocumentRoot /path/to/rails/application/public

It means it should point to the public folder of your rails application.
To create a new rails application `rails new SomeName`

Comment: Oh, well that seems fair. I thought i had to do it for rails itself. Not the app! I'm gonna try it when i'm back home. Thanks!